# Set defaultProxy in app.config at runtime

Tags: c#, soap, app-config

I'm working on a SOAP-Client capsuled in a COM-dll. Unfortunately I can't deliver an app.config, so I have to insert my values on runtime:

```
        try
        {
            var dataSet = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.data") as System.Data.DataSet;
            dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Add("FirebirdClient Data Provider"
            , ".Net Framework Data Provider for Firebird"
            , "FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient"
            , "FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FirebirdClientFactory, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient, Version=2.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3750abcc3150b00c");              
        }
        catch
        { }
```

But I have no Idea how to set the default-Proxy at runtime:

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true"/>
</system.net>
```

Without this option I can't communicate through a Proxy...

```
BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(Adress);

ServiceReference.DataTransferationServiceSoap serviceClient = new ServiceReference.DataTransferationServiceSoapClient(basicHttpBinding, endpointAddress);

serviceClient.doSomething();
```

How can I set the useDefaultCredentials at runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do the following:

```
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

This will set the credentials to be used by the default web proxy to the default credentials, which should have the same effect as `useDefaultCredentials="true"`.

Comment: Working perfectly. Thank you ^^